# Adding the values in the list recursively and returning the partial sums

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I have a list [1,2,3,4]. My function should return [1,3,6,10]. This is what I have so far. I have tried to make a helper method that takes the value and keeps it to a list and adds it. But it does not seem to work.

```
summed = []

help x = (x + summed x) : summed  

summing [] = [] 
summing (x:xs) = help x : summing xs
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer, because this sounds like homework.  But there are several approaches.

You’re on the right track.  If you want to write a function with two parameters: the sum so far, and the input list.  If you pass the `tail` of the list to the next iteration, the number you want to add to the accumulating sum will be the head of the list you pass in.

You might also look at the higher-order functions in `Data.List` for one that takes as its arguments the function `(+)`, an initial value, and a list and returns a repeated application of the function to each element of the list, then returns a list of the results, not just a final result.  What you’re doing is an important pattern to learn.

Comment: But how do I keep the list with the sum so far. I'm confused about that.

Comment: the sum so far will be the last number pushed into the list of results of repeated applications to the function, right?

Comment: @AdamSmith Yeah. But I'm having a hard time adding it and sending it back.

Comment: @RandomCoder The hint above suggests that you try `summing xs = helper xs initialValue` and then defining `helper xs v` recursively, doing the obvious cases on `xs`. In the recursive call, you can use `helper ys next_v`, so to pass on a new value of `v`. In this way, you can make `v` be the sum of the values seen so far.

Comment: You can do it in several ways. First, you don’t need to keep a list if you do it the way you were doing. The running sum, and the head of the input list, are enough information to calculate each new item `x'` on the list, and you can return `x':(summing x' xs)`. Second, you could keep the output list as an accumulating parameter, although for lists, it’s only efficient to build it in reverse order. (What happens when you try to add something to the *tail* of an immutable list whose nodes can only be copied, not changed? What do you need to do to the previous node, then the one before it?)

Answer (score 1):

`scanl (+) 0 yourList` should do it. You can read up on how it's implemented and why by looking through GHC's standard library documentation and sources. https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/libraries/base-4.16.0.0/src/GHC-List.html#scanl

Comment: It has to be done recursively.

Comment: `scanl (+) 0` is going to add `0` to the front of the result array. `scanl1 (+)` would fix it.

Comment: @4castle But that's using a higher order function. I have to do it recursively.

Comment: @RandomCoder Right, but you can inspect the source code of those functions in order to get a recursive one.

Comment: @RandomCoder that's why I suggested you "read up on how it's implemented and why by looking through GHC's standard library documentation and sources." `scanl` IS written recursively. All you have to do is read it.